# cryptsetup not unlocking at boot

Tags: linux, debian, encryption, mount, luks

I have these two files:

/etc/crypttab:

```
cry1    /dev/sda3   none                    luks
cry2    /dev/sda4   /mounted/sda3/keyfile   luks
```

/etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sda1           /boot    ext2   ro        0   2
/dev/sda2           /        ext4   defaults  0   0
/dev/mapper/cry1    /cry1    ext4   defaults  0   2
/dev/mapper/cry2    /cry2    ext4   defaults  0   2
```

Debian boots and I am prompted for the password for the sda3/cry1 file system. It works and it is mounted.

But sda4/cry2 is not mounted although I can easily decrypt and mount it on the command line, not only with a password, but also with the keyfile.

I ended up putting the command line on /etc/rc.local but I am not happy with that arragement. Why is the crypttab/fstab mechanism not working?

Also: I am worried that rebooting or shutting down the system does not umount and decrypt the file systems cleanly, and that might corrupt the file system. How can I ensure everything is shut down cleanly?

Answer (score 0):

So `/dev/sda3` gets luksOpen'ed to `/dev/mapper/cry1`, which gets mounted to `/cry1`? What/where is `/mounted/sda3`? It sounds like it should be sda3, maybe that's the problem...

Anyway, if the mountpoints are correct I sounds like a timing problem with mounting. crypttab is supposed to go through the entries sequentially, but I'm not sure if they get mounted before the next entry, there are a couple options in `man crypttab` that sound promising.

Try adding this one to the `cry2` entry:

```
   noearly
       The cryptsetup init scripts are invoked twice during the boot process -
       once before lvm, raid, etc. are started and once again after that.
       Sometimes you need to start your encrypted disks in a special order.
       With this option the device is ignored during the first invocation of
       the cryptsetup init scripts.
```

And try this option too & check logs to see what it says the problem is:

```
   loud
       Be loud. Print warnings if a device does not exist. This option
       overwrites the option quiet.
```

This is an idea if you don't find any way other than running your own custom script:

```
   keyscript=<path>
       The executable at the indicated path is executed with the key file from
       the third field of the crypttab as its only argument and the output is
       used as the key. This also works with encrypted root filesystems via
       initramfs if the executable is self-contained (i.e. an executable which
       does not rely on any external program which is not present in the
       initramfs environment).
```

---

At shutdown, everything *should* be unmounted, if some filesystems aren't it might be a more general problem to search for, I'm not sure if it would be automatically related to encryption.